# Google Amp lighbox doesn't work on safari

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to use webp images and have my jpg as fallback. My images open up in a lightbox. On firefox and chrome everything works fine, but on safari clicking on the image the screen freezes.

```
 <amp-img
              lightbox="hero"
              alt="katarina wearing zara"
              src="portfolio/katarina_wearing_zara.webp"
              width="500"
              height="500"
              layout="intrinsic"
            >
              <amp-img
                fallback="fallback"
                lightbox="herofallback"
                alt="katarina wearing zara"
                src="portfolio/katarina_wearing_zara.jpg"
                srcset="portfolio/katarina_wearing_zara.jpg 1500w,
              portfolio/katarina_wearing_zara_1125w.jpg 1125w,
              portfolio/katarina_wearing_zara_750w.jpg 750w,
              portfolio/katarina_wearing_zara_375w.jpg 375w"
                width="500"
                height="500"
                layout="intrinsic"
              ></amp-img>
            </amp-img>
```

is there something i am missing?

Comment: can you see the target image on safari without using `<amp-img>`?

Comment: Safari doesn't support webp format, so it fallbacks to the inner amp-img, however clicking on it, it freezes the application, am not sure what is happening. I think its trying to open a lightbox with the webp format pictures instead of the herofallback lightbox

Comment: that may be a bug with `amp-image-lightbox`. try removing `="hero"` (leaving just `lightbox`). also, try removing `lightbox="herofallback"` - i believe the parent `lightbox` is in control and that no further control is required for fallback. there are several safari issues on amp.dev. if suggestion fails, open a new issue and use the example above. the amp.dev developers are very responsive to these types of issues.

Comment: nextjs will set lightbox="true" if i just put lightbox.

Comment: right, but you have `lightbox="hero"` which IMHO is the problem.